# Issue with UI-Select and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I'm currently getting an error in the console that says:

```
    Error: [ui.select:items] Expected an array but got '{}'.at select.min.js:7
at select.min.js:7
at $watchCollectionAction (angular.js:16527)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16664)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16928)
at done (angular.js:11266)
at completeRequest (angular.js:11464)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11405)
```

I'm returning the content from a webservice which I have checked in postman which returns an array and 80% of the time it's not working to populate the pull-down menu and the other 20% of the time I get the error but it still works.

The code is pretty simple:

```
    function selectCtrl($scope, $http) {

$scope.person = {};

$scope.option = {};
$scope.options = [];


var onUserComplete = function(response){
    $scope.options = response.data;
    console.log(response.data);
}


$http.get("http://localhost/api/user")
    .then(onUserComplete);
```

}

HTML looks like this:

```
                        <ui-select ng-model="option.selected" theme="bootstrap" on-select="onSelectCallback($item)">
                            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a person">{{$select.selected.username}}</ui-select-match>
                            <ui-select-choices repeat="item in options">
                                <div ng-bind-html="item.username | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                            </ui-select-choices>
                        </ui-select>
```

Data in postman looks like this:

```
    [
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "username1"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "username2"
}
```

]

Comment: Maybe sometimes its returning an `object ({})` instead of `array ([])`, please check if its an array if there is only one element in the response!

Comment: I just did this console.log(Array.isArray($scope.options)); and it came out true.

Comment: when the issue occours console.log the data and replicate the issue in a jsfiddle with that data, since postman does not work with jsfiddle, it will help to solve this problem